# Why are css settings leaking into other components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a number of react class components where I include `.css` files. Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import "./Payment.css"

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

class PaymentModal extends React.Component {
...
```

But these `.css` settings are being applied in other components. Why are css settings leaking into other components?

Comment: Because the css is not module-scoped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing stopping CSS styles "leaking" is unique names. CSS modules use a technique of adding some random string to class names to ensure this uniqueness. From your code it looks like you are just importing some raw CSS into your component. If that is the case, you need to ensure you use unique classes and selectors to prevent the CSS being over-applied. It's easier with SASS/LESS, since it's easy to put all our selectors inside some parent class selector like:

```
    .my-modal {
        input.my-input {
           color: #fff; 
        }
    }
```

or whatever - the point being you can nest your selectors in a way you can't in plain CSS.

So my suggestion is to either use a CSS module library, use SASS with nested selectors, or simply be careful about ensuring your CSS selectors are unique.

Comment: Thanks! Converting to `SCSS` worked. (We already had it set up)